# How can add values in each row and column and print at the end in Perl?

Tags: perl, csv

Below is the sample csv file

```
date,type1,type2,.....
2009-07-01,n1,n2,.....
2009-07-02,n21,n22,....
and so on...
```

I want to add the values in each row and each column and print at the end and bottom of each line. i.e.

```
date,type1,type2
2009-07-01,n1,n2,.....row_total1
2009-07-02,n21,n22,....row_total2
Total,col_total1,col_total1,......total
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like JB's perlgolf candidate, except prints the end line totals and labels.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -alnF,
use List::Util qw(sum);
chomp;
push @F, $. == 1 ? "total" : sum(@F[1..$#F]);
print "$_,$F[-1]";
for (my $i=1;$i<@F;$i++) {
    $totals[$i] += $F[$i];
}
END {
    $totals[0] = "Total";
    print join(",",@totals);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Less elegant and shorter:

```
$ perl -plaF, -e '$r=0;$r+=$F[$_],$c[$_]+=$F[$_]for 1..$#F;$_.=",$r";END{$c[0]="Total";print join",",@c}'
```

Quick and dirty, but should do the trick in basic cases.  For anything more complex, use Text::CSV and an actual script.

An expanded version as it's getting a little hairy:

```
#! perl -plaF,
$r=0;
$r+=$F[$_], $c[$_]+=$F[$_] for 1..$#F;
$_.=",$r";
END { $c[0]="Total"; print join ",", @c }'
```

Comment: I think you mean 'perl -plaF,'  (The backslash before the comma may be necessary in some shells)

Comment: Precisely. That and a few other fixes ;) Thanks

Comment: Thanks, This gives me the addition values of each column, how to use this for each row.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward way which you can easily build upon depending on your requirements:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use List::Util qw(sum);
use List::MoreUtils qw(pairwise);
use Text::ParseWords;

our ($a, $b);
my @header = parse_csv( scalar <DATA> );
my @total  = (0) x @header;
output_csv( @header, 'row_total' );

for my $line (<DATA>) {
    my @cols  = parse_csv( $line );
    my $label = shift @cols;
    push @cols, sum @cols;
    output_csv( $label, @cols );
    @total = pairwise { $a + $b } @total, @cols;
}

output_csv( 'Total', @total );

sub parse_csv { 
    chomp( my $data = shift );
    quotewords ',', 0, $data; 
}

sub output_csv { say join ',' => @_ }

__DATA__
date,type1,type2
2009-07-01,1,2
2009-07-02,21,22
```

Outputs the expected:

> ```
> date,type1,type2,row_total
> 2009-07-01,1,2,3
> 2009-07-02,21,22,43
> Total,22,24,46
> ```

Some things to take away from above is the use of [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scalar-List-Utils/lib/List/Util.pm) and [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/):

```
# using List::Util::sum
my $sum_of_all_values_in_list = sum @list;

# using List::MoreUtils::pairwise
my @two_arrays_added_together = pairwise { $a + $b } @array1, @array2;
```

Also while I've used [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-ParseWords/) in my example you should really look into using [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV/).   This modules covers more bizarre CSV edge cases and also provides correct CSV composition (my output_csv() sub is pretty naive!).

/I3az/

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that needs to be done for sure in a Perl script?  There is no "quick and dirty" method to do this in Perl.  You will need to read the file in, accumulate your totals, and write the file back out (processing input and output line by line would be the cleanest).

If this is a one-time report, or you are working with a competent user base, the data you want can most easily be produced with a spreadsheet program like Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The following in Perl does what you want, its not elegant but it works :-)
Call the script with the inputfile as argument, results in stdout.

```
chop($_ = <>);

print "$_,Total\n";

while (<>) {

    chop;
    split(/,/);
    shift(@_);

    $sum = 0;

    for ($n = 0; 0 < scalar(@_); $n++) {
        $c = shift(@_);
        $sum += $c;
        $sums[$n] += $c;
    }

    $total += $sum;

    print "$_,$sum\n";
}

print "Total";

for ($n = 0; $n <= $#sums; $n++) {

    print "," . $sums[$n];
}

print ",$total\n";
```

**Edit**: fixed for 0 values.

The output is like this:

```
date,type1,type2,type3,Total
2009-07-01,1, 2, 3,6
2009-07-02,4, 5, 6,15
Total,5,7,9,21
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but can calculates the values until 0 comes. Can you please suggest how to add the fields with 0 values as well.

Comment: Don't use `chop`, use `chomp`.

Comment: @Sinan, don't mark down for such a minor issue. (not all Perl versions have  chomp)

Comment: @rsp: I am facing one more issue. If the next column has empty column, its adding values untill empty comes. Can you please help me.

Comment: @Virus, edited to fix that issue, I changed the method of determining when the end of the columns is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I work with CSV, I use the [`AnyData`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/AnyData) module.  It may add a bit of overhead, but it keeps me from making mistakes ("Oh crap, that date column is quoted and has commas in it!?").
The process for you would look something like this:

```
use AnyData;
my @columns = qw/date type1 type2 type3/;  ## Define your input columns.
my $input = adTie( 'CSV', 'input_file.csv', 'r', {col_names => join(',', @columns)} );
push @columns, 'total';  ## Add the total columns.
my $output = adTie( 'CSV', 'output_file.csv', 'o', {col_names => join(',', @columns)} );
my %totals;
while ( my $row = each %$input ) {
    next if ($. == 1);  ## Skip the header row.  AnyData will add it to the output.
    my $sum = 0;
    foreach my $col (@columns[1..3]) {
        $totals{$col} += $row->{$col};
        $sum += $row->{$col};
    }
    $totals{total} += $sum;
    $row->{total} = $sum;
    $output->{$row->{date}} = $row;
}
$output->{Total} = \%totals;
print adDump( $output ); ## Prints a little table to see the data.  Not required.
undef $input; ## Close the file.
undef $output;
```

Input:

```
date,type1,type2,type3
2009-07-01,1,2,3
2009-07-03,31,32,33
2009-07-06,61,62,63
"Dec 31, 1969",81,82,83
```

Output:

```
date,type1,type2,type3,total
2009-07-01,1,2,3,6
2009-07-03,31,32,33,96
2009-07-06,61,62,63,186
"Dec 31, 1969",81,82,83,246
Total,174,178,182,534
```